# how to change the direction of the ActionBar back button in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-navigation

i have a `Android ActionBar back button` want to change back button default `andorid` to left but befor that i changed `navigationView` direction with using layoutDirection="rtl" for `DrawerLayout` . now `ActionBar` back button is under `navigationView` and i dont know how to change direction that .

**note :** i dont want to use a custom menu for create back button .

**xml :**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.user.classmanager.StudentListActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_StudentList"
style="@style/DrawerLayout_all"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout_StudentList"
    style="@style/Width_height_all_both_matchParent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_StudentList"
        style="@style/ToolBar_all"
        />
         .
         .  
         .
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView_StudentList"
    style="@style/NavigationView_StudentList"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**style :**

```
<style name="DrawerLayout_all" parent="Width_height_all_both_matchParent">

    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>

</style>
```

**activity :**

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_StudentList);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);actionBar title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); buttons
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Check this out: [RTL Support on Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2) I think you should use android:supportsRtl="true" in your activity.